# Is there a way to use wild cards, redirection or other shell syntax with systemd units?

Tags: systemd, services, wildcards

I have a systemd file to start a jar file. But I want to execute jar file as `*.jar`. Is there a way to do this?

```
[Unit]
Description=Test Background

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/java -jar /var/www/test.com/*.jar
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/test.com

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I tried this but not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [`man 5 systemd.service`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man5/systemd.service.5.html#command%20lines) (section "Command Lines"):

```
This syntax is inspired by shell syntax, but only the meta-characters and expansions
described in the following paragraphs are understood, and the expansion of variables is
different. Specifically, redirection using "<", "<<", ">", and ">>", pipes using "|",
running programs in the background using "&", and other elements of shell syntax are not
supported.
```

And:

```
Note that shell command lines are not directly supported. If shell command lines are to be
used, they need to be passed explicitly to a shell implementation of some kind. Example:

   ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'dmesg | tac'
```

Wildcards are not mentioned as being supported, so you'll have to wrap that command in `/bin/sh -c` or `/bin/bash -c` like in the above example.